# TP4056 connected all time

Tags: batteries

I have board with [TP4056](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) which will be used to charge Li-ion battery. But I wanted to use battery as a back-up power. So it's possible to have power connected to TP4056 all the time? Or it can damage battery?

Comment: No, we're not going to look up what a "TP4056" is just to answer a question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, TP4056 is designed to be connected and powered all the time, it will automatically stop and restart charging cycles as necessary. This is all written on the first page of the datasheet:

> The
>   TP4056 **automatically terminates the charge** cycle when the charge current drops to 1/10th the
>   programmed value after the final float voltage is reached.
>   TP4056 Other features include current monitor, under voltage lockout, **automatic recharge** and
>   two status pin to indicate charge termination and the presence of an input voltage.